# dyld: Library not loaded: reason image not found for UI Test target

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working in project which uses the framework produced by another project in the same workspace. Project works fine and uses framework without any issue, but it crashes when I try to run XCode-generated UITest with error:
`dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/MyProj.framework/MyProj
  Referenced from: /Users/developer/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B2194BA8-9577-4916-A396-BF2B3A04DEA7/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/445A97AF-470B-4698-8785-AEFA836E126C/MySpecProj.app/MySpecProj
  Reason: image not found`

So, my suspicion is that UITest target somehow can't load framework which MyProjFramework generates, but in the same time I can start the app and it works fine with framework

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue.

The App target that my UITest target was launching, had a duplicate dependency. Interestingly, out of the pair, one of them was highlighted red.

I removed all of my dependencies, cleared derived data, then re-added all and that solved the issue.